# CakePHP / General HTML Email

Tags: email, cakephp

In my application when I send emails I send them as HTML rather than Text. However is it possible for the user to only view HTML emails? I have looked in my Gmail settings and haven't seen anything on this... What happens if they did choose Text Only and I was only sending HTML emails, would they not get the sent email?

Just to clarify, the user isn't choosing the type of email from the application. I'm deciding this in the Controller so it's just HTML only! But I'm wondering what happens if a user can or did choose Text only emails in their email client... Would they block my emails?

Just a bit curious. Thanks

Comment: *"...if they choose Text Only..."* Do you mean within their e-mail client or within your application?

Answer (score 0):

You should just send both and then the email client will decide what's best to view (based on their preferences).

If you don't want to maintain view files for the text-only emails, you could override the `_render()` function in the `EmailComponent` to automatically strip the tags of the html one.

Comment: I tried that and I just ended up getting two emails in my Gmail inbox.

Comment: Are you using `sendAs => both`? Because I use it on a regular basis and only receive one.

Comment: Yes and I got both the text and HTML version sent to me.

Comment: Seems it may be related to this bug: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2022-duplicate-emails-are-being-sent-by-cakeemail